# Check if Wordpress User exists by email

Tags: php, wordpress

For the life of me I cant get this to work (default example from WP Codex). I created a php file with this code and dropped it in my theme folder, when I access the file on the web I get a blank page, nada -- am I missing something, do i have to put this someplace else? any help is greatly appreciated.

```
  <?php
  $email = 'myemail@example.com';
  $exists = email_exists($email);
  if ( $exists )
  echo "That E-mail is registered to user number " . $exists;
  else
  echo "That E-mail doesn't belong to any registered users on this site";
  ?>
```

Comment: You should turn on debugging. A white page means there's a PHP error somewhere.

Comment: I ran your code in fiddle and got this `Call to undefined function email_exists()` so check your `email_exists` function as i can't see in your code from where it is coming may b you forget to include a file

Comment: can you please answer these questions so we can help you ... where did you put your php code exactly ? in which file ? what is your php file name ? and how are you trying to access it.

Answer (score 5):

simple answer,
If that is the template page, than use this:

```
<?php
  $email = 'myemail@example.com';
  $exists = email_exists($email);
  if ( $exists )
  echo "That E-mail is registered to user number ";
  else
  echo "That E-mail doesn't belong to any registered users on this site";
  ?>
```

and ensure you have correct opening and closing php tags.

But if are from other than tempalte page then use this:

```
<?php
  require_once("../../../../wp-load.php");  //ADD THIS

  $email = 'myemail@example.com';
  $exists = email_exists($email);
  if ( $exists )
  echo "That E-mail is registered to user number ";
  else
  echo "That E-mail doesn't belong to any registered users on this site";
  ?>
```

Add or Remove ../ in the require_once("../../../../wp-load.php") as per the page location.
This will surely help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add **wp-load.php** in your file with ***right path.***

```
<?php
  require_once("../../../wp-load.php");  //ADD THIS

  $email = 'myemail@example.com';
  $exists = email_exists($email);
  if ( $exists )
  echo "That E-mail is registered to user number " . $exists;
  else
  echo "That E-mail doesn't belong to any registered users on this site";
  ?>
```